# Python- ignore special characters and match only text

Tags: python, string

I am trying to check if a string exists in list:

My string is without any special characters like {,},\n,\n\n

```
string1='hi'
string2='I'
string3='am new to this'
```

where as my list entry contains strings like:

```
list_count="{hi}","\n I","am \n new {to} this\n\n"
```

I want to know how can i check for a match of strings by considering only the "text part" of list

Note: I am having n number of strings to check in list

I have tried below code, seems to not work my purpose

strings=string1,string2,string3

code:

```
for i in strings:
    if i in list_count:
        print('yes')
```

I want the output to be yes for checks like:

```
if 'hi' in list_count:
```

It has to print yes by only checking for text part and not including '{' '}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `list_count` by removing special characters, spaces etc.

```
list_count="{hi}","\n I","am \n new {to} this\n\n"
string1='hi'
string2='I'
string3='am new to this'
strings=string1,string2,string3

ignored = ['{','}','\n']

final_list = []
for item in list_count:
    for k in ignored:
        # remove special characters
        item = item.replace(k,"")
    # remove extra spaces
    item = " ".join(item.split())
    final_list.append(item)

for i in strings:
    if i in final_list:
        print('yes')
```

Comment: this will not be scalable, for each special character you will have to update your code first. Also this is unnecessarily complicating the code. There is absolutely no performance, efficiency or value add by converting the `list_count` to non-special character list first and then checking, but on the contrary

Comment: @Shivam Singh This is working for few cases. For few there are whitespace in between which is not getting striped.
I am trying this to remove whitespace present after replacing the ignored char.
`code` for item in inp:
    for k in ignored:
        # remove special characters
        item = item.replace(k,'')
    # remove extra spaces
    item = " ".join(item.split())
    final_list.append(item.strip())

Comment: final_list has some strings with whitespaces and it not getting striped bz of which the condition is failing

Comment: Please give an exact example of `final_list`, I already removed whitespaces by `item = " ".join(item.split())`. It should be working.

Comment: @Shivam Singh  In final_list I am getting some strings as below:
`  list_count="hi","I","am new  \nto this" `
Instead of:
`list_count="hi","I","am new to this"`

Comment: What is the value of `list_count` in this case?

Comment: `list_count="hi","I","am new \n to this" ` this is not the required thing

Comment: Change `ignored = ['{','}','\n','\\n']` which I think might be the case here

Comment: @Shivam Singh found the issue. Thanks. Had to add ' ' to ignored list